# Pandas doesnt make a file from the data I give it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to scrape certain information from multiple pages into an excel file. The scraping part works, but I cant manage to figure out why the pandas DataFrame doesnt work. Python doesnt give me any errors regarding maybe a syntax error, and the code does runs, but no actual file gets created. I think the issue lies with maybe that I'm trying to scrape multiple pages into an excel file, but I have no clue! (Ive crossed out some sensitive login and website info).

The goal is to end up with an excel file that has the artikelnummer, prijzen and voorraad as columns, and the scraped data as the values.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep 
import pandas as pandas


username = "x"
password = "x"
url = 'https://xx/nl_NL/login'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)


driver.implicitly_wait(2)

email = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email")
pswrd = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"password")

email.send_keys(username)
pswrd.send_keys(password)
sleep(2)

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//nvs-button[text()="Inloggen"]')
sleep(2)
login.click()
sleep(2)


driver.get('https://shop.libra.energy/nl_NL/category/solar/zonnepanelen')
sleep(1)
cookies = driver.find_element(By.ID, "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowallSelection")
sleep(1)
cookies.click()
sleep(1)

result = []
for i in range(4):

     
     firstSearch = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ("t-list-view"))
     artikelnummer = firstSearch.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//small[@class="flex flex-wrap gap-x-1"]')
     prijzen =  firstSearch.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="m-product-price m-product-price--expanded"]')
     voorraad =  firstSearch.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="m-product-availability m-product-availability--size-small m-product-availability--status-success leading-4"]')
     sleep(2)
     
     
     for a in range(len(artikelnummer)):
          temp = {'Artikelnummer': artikelnummer[i].text, 
                  'Prijzen': prijzen[i].text,
                  'Voorraad':voorraad[i].text}
          result.append(temp)

     df_data = pandas.DataFrame(result)

     nextPage= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Volgende pagina"]')
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextPage)

     sleep(2)

df_data.to_excel('Voorraadprojectie.csv', index=False)

     
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can use a few `print`s (or a debugger) to find out what `result` and `df_data` contain to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What is the dataframe that pandas tries to write into the file? As @MichaelButscher said, you can use a print statement to see if those values are set correctly.

Comment: The line `df_data = pandas.DataFrame(result)` is indented so as to be within the outer  loop; I don't think that is what you intend and it should be outside the loop. That said use `print(result)` before forming the DF to check contents of the List.

Comment: Yes you're completely right! However, I wasnt sure of how to do that yet so I thought Id figure out getting some results first, and wasnt aware of that it might impact the creation of the file! Thanks!! Ive added a print result (inside of the loop that is) and it does give me all the information I need, now I just need to figure out how to add it all together. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the command `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` with the doc here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let me point at some points of your code:

1. `to_excel` should be using for creating an xlsx file, and `to_csv` for csv file.
2. Are you sure you are seeing the right folder? I am asking because you don't specify the full path of your 'Voorraadprojectie.csv' file, and it may generates somewhere else.
3. *Additional*: You added the `df_data = pandas.DataFrame(result)` row **inside** of a for cycle. You should define outside of the for loop, and append (`concat`) all the gathered data.

Comment: 1. Youre completely right! I altered it, however, still no luck!
2. Im sure, Ive searched through my entire computer but couldnt find it
3. I'll look into this for sure! That was indeed my next step, but I wasnt sure of how to actually do that yet